# Включить отступы в ширину блока

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
Есть код табов https://jsfiddle.net/nore0x3e/3/

Как видите, кнопки и контент который выводится под ними, растягиваются. У кнопок width:33.33%; у контента который ниже 100%.
Все бы отлично, но стоит добавить у кнопок отступ и последняя кнопка уже переносится на новую строку.
Тут бы помог:

```
    margin-right:6px; 
    box-sizing:padding-box;
```

Но в хроме такая конструкция не работает (padding-box не поддерживается), а вот в файрфоксе отлично.

Так же бы мне помогло:

```
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Но у моих кнопок углы закругленны, в отступ в виде правого белого бордера, получается внутри кнопки, а не снаружи, да и кнопки уже имеют бордер.

В общем, как сделать чтобы блок с кнопками поиска и контент который ниже, растягивались во всю ширину монитора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
width: calc(33.33% - 6px);
margin-right: 6px;
```

Comment: я бы еще добавил `.tabs ul.tabs-list li:last-child{
  width: 33.33%;
  margin-right:0;
}`
чтобы последний элемент лучше смотрелся.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, оба кода выше очень помогли мне.